# Can't change the caption of a UIButton from its own Touch Up Inside event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit, ibaction

I just noticed this crazy behavior in UIButton:

If I try to set the caption of a UIButton from an IBAction that gets fired on the button's touch up inside event, the caption changes, but is quickly reverted to the old value.

If I do it in some other button's touch up inside event, it works as expected.

What monkey business is going on???

```
- (IBAction)removeText:(id)sender {

    [[sender titleLabel] setText:@"New Text"];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

titleLabel is a read-only property. You want to use:

```
[sender setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Edit: Actually, looking it up the titleLabel's own properties are still accessible, but nevertheless the setTitle solution is the way to go....

Answer (score 0):

Correct way would be :

```
- (IBAction)removeText:(id)sender {
   [(UIButton*)sender setTitle:@"New Text" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```